# Javascript iterating through array issue

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, d3.js

I currently have this code:

```
var values = [
[3.5,3,3.2,3.1,3.6,3.9,3.4,3.4,2.9,3.1,3.7,3.4,3,3,4,4.4,3.9,3.5,3.8,3.8,3.4,3.7,3.6,3.3,3.4,3,3.4,3.5,3.4,3.2,3.1,3.4,4.1,4.2,3.1,3.2,3.5,3.1,3,3.4,3.5,2.3,3.2,3.5,3.8,3,3.8,3.2,3.7,3.3,3.2,3.2,3.1,2.3,2.8,2.8,3.3,2.4,2.9,2.7,2,3,2.2,2.9,2.9,3.1,3,2.7,2.2,2.5,3.2,2.8,2.5,2.8,2.9,3,2.8,3,2.9,2.6,2.4,2.4,2.7,2.7,3,3.4,3.1,2.3,3,2.5,2.6,3,2.6,2.3,2.7,3,2.9,2.9,2.5,2.8,3.3,2.7,3,2.9,3,3,2.5,2.9,2.5,3.6,3.2,2.7,3,2.5,2.8,3.2,3,3.8,2.6,2.2,3.2,2.8,2.8,2.7,3.3,3.2,2.8,3,2.8,3,2.8,3.8,2.8,2.8,2.6,3,3.4,3.1,3,3.1,3.1,3.1,2.7,3.2,3.3,3,2.5,3,3.4,3],
[5.1,4.9,4.7,4.6,5,5.4,4.6,5,4.4,4.9,5.4,4.8,4.8,4.3,5.8,5.7,5.4,5.1,5.7,5.1,5.4,5.1,4.6,5.1,4.8,5,5,5.2,5.2,4.7,4.8,5.4,5.2,5.5,4.9,5,5.5,4.9,4.4,5.1,5,4.5,4.4,5,5.1,4.8,5.1,4.6,5.3,5,7,6.4,6.9,5.5,6.5,5.7,6.3,4.9,6.6,5.2,5,5.9,6,6.1,5.6,6.7,5.6,5.8,6.2,5.6,5.9,6.1,6.3,6.1,6.4,6.6,6.8,6.7,6,5.7,5.5,5.5,5.8,6,5.4,6,6.7,6.3,5.6,5.5,5.5,6.1,5.8,5,5.6,5.7,5.7,6.2,5.1,5.7,6.3,5.8,7.1,6.3,6.5,7.6,4.9,7.3,6.7,7.2,6.5,6.4,6.8,5.7,5.8,6.4,6.5,7.7,7.7,6,6.9,5.6,7.7,6.3,6.7,7.2,6.2,6.1,6.4,7.2,7.4,7.9,6.4,6.3,6.1,7.7,6.3,6.4,6,6.9,6.7,6.9,5.8,6.8,6.7,6.7,6.3,6.5,6.2,5.9]
];
var counter = 0;

function updateGauges() {
    if (counter < values[0].length) {
        for (var key in gauges) {
            gauges[key].redraw(values[key][counter]);
            //gauges[key].redraw(getRandomValue(gauges[key]));
        }
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    else {
        counter = 0;
        clearInterval(timerid);
    }
}

function getRandomValue(gauge) {
    var overflow = 0; //10;
    return gauge.config.min - overflow + (gauge.config.max - gauge.config.min + overflow*2) *  Math.random();
}
```

When I try to run this, my D3 gauge doesn't show the values. However, if I replace the uncommented line with the commented line, it runs fine.

Am I not defining my multidimensional array properly?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure gauges[key] = values[key][counter]?^_^

Comment: Maybe it is `values[0][counter]` instead of `values[key][counter]`?

Comment: values[key][counter] needs key to increment so that each gauge on the screen is changed. My logic was that for each gauge, take the value in the first and then second arrays in the "values" array of arrays. After updateGauges gets run over and over again by a setInterval, the counter would increment, so that each gauge would have the next element of its respective data set array inside "values" loaded into the gauge.

@Danyu: I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: Having values[0][counter] seems to work, albeit only taking the values of the first array inside "values". This leads me to believe that "var key" isn't actually an integer. This frustrates me due to my conditioning in explicit variable types.

Comment: EDIT: Apparently I lack basic understanding of how arrays work in Javascript, as apparently you can refer to an array element using a string and not an index.

Comment: From your code it is not clear which values `key` can have. If `key` is greater than 1, than you will get undefined value for ` values[key][counter]`

Comment: Instead of trying to iterate through each gauge usng [key], I made a separate index counter for it, and it now iterates properly. Thanks for the help, everyone.